# Sending values to database with Python (SenseHAT project)

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've got a SenseHAT for my Raspberry PI 3 and I want to send some values to an external database.

Here's my **.py** file :

```
import time
import pymysql.cursors
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

temperature = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
pressure = round(sense.get_pressure(), 1)
humidity = round(sense.get_humidity(), 1)

connection = pymysql.connect(host='HOSTNAME',
                             user='USERNAME',
                             password='PASSWORD',
                             db='DATABASE',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = "INSERT INTO data SET dat_date=%d, dat_time=%d, dat_temperature=%d, dat_pressure=%d, dat_humidity=%d, idx_sensor=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%H:%M:%s"),float(temperature),float(pressure),float(humidity),int(1)))

    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()

sense.show_message("T:" + str(temperature) + " P:" + str(pressure) + " H:" + str(humidity), scroll_speed=0.7)
```

My problem occurs while running the SQL query. I created in `sql` the query and I execute it in the line below by assigning values ​​to the variables. However, I still have an error message that occurs, even when I change the type of value to insert (`%s` and `%d`).

Here's the values :

- `dat_date` => MySQL DATE (2017-12-11)
- `dat_time` => MySQL TIME (15:44:54)
- `dat_temperature` => Temperature from the SenseHAT (32.6)
- `dat_pressure` => Pressure from the SenseHAT (654.98)
- `dat_humidity` => Humidity from the SenseHAT (12.6)
- `idx_sensor` => Raspberry PI ID (**1** in this case)

Here's the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sh_sr.py", line 22, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%H:%M:%s"),float(temperature),float(pressure),float(humidity),int(1)))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

So, does anyone see what am I doing wrong ?

(This is the first time I developpe something with Python.)

I'm using Raspbian => last version 11.12.2017 and PyMySQL installed with `pip`

Comment: You need use `%s`, : what is your error with `%s` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add simple quote and use `%s`

```
sql = "INSERT INTO data SET dat_date='%s', dat_time='%s', dat_temperature=%s, dat_pressure=%s, dat_humidity=%s, idx_sensor=%s"
```

Comment: I put `%s` everywhere and it's working ... I don't understand when we need to use `%s` or `%d`

Comment: Where have found doc about `%d` ? For me we can only use `%s` : http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html